# Gotomeeting streaming protocol

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, citrix, http-live-streaming

I am building a `live-streaming` solution for my company. I am trying using `HLS` but I found there is lots of delay PLUS buffering.

I have found that when my clients were using `gotowebinar` then there was no `delay` as well as less or no `buffering`.

I heard that `gotowebinar` is `RTMP` if it is so then it needs flash then how they are working on `IOS devices` ?

Can anyone help me to understand how `gotowebinar` is managing so efficiently ?

Comment: There are open-source libs for RTMP on iOS but you will need to create a dedicated app. For HLS you can reduce the segment duration.

Comment: Use WebRTC for this.